# How to make SJCL and Python hashlib generate identical pdkdf2 output

Tags: javascript, python, hmac

I have a JavaScript app and a Python app that communicate using a key derived from a password using pbdkf2. The problem is, the generated keys don't match. I've produced a minimal test case for each.

**Python**

```
import hashlib, binascii
bytes = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', "password".encode(), b'', 100000)
print(binascii.hexlify(bytes).decode())
```

Generates: `64a868d4b23af696d3734d0b814d04cdd1ac280128e97653a05f32b49c13a29a`

**JavaScript**

```
<script src="lib/sjcl.js"></script>
<script>
var hmacSHA256 = function (key) {
    var hasher = new sjcl.misc.hmac(key, sjcl.hash.sha256);
    this.encrypt = function () {
        return hasher.encrypt.apply(hasher, arguments);
    };
};
hash = sjcl.misc.pbkdf2("password", [0], 100000, 256, hmacSHA256);
console.log(sjcl.codec.hex.fromBits(hash));
</script>
```

Generates: `41c04f824d843d5be0ae66b3f621d3f05db7d47e7c46ee0e9171b5cbff7f3631`

I'm scratching my head a lot now. I think `b''` and `[0]` are equivalent salts, but I'm not sure. I think they both use utf-8 to encode the password, but I'm not sure. And I'm not convinced the JavaScript hmacSHA256 function exactly matches what Python is doing. Or it could be something else still.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Off the top of my head, have you checked if

```
hash = sjcl.misc.pbkdf2("password", "", 100000, 256);
```

gives the correct result?

As far as I can tell from the [docs](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/doc/symbols/sjcl.misc.html), SJCL's PBKDF2 implementation defaults to HMAC-SHA256 if you don't explicitly give it a PRF.  If making that change fixes the bug, then there's probably something wrong with your `hmacSHA256` wrapper.

Also, I'm not sure if specifying an empty salt as `[0]` really works (or is guaranteed to work in future versions, given that the format of SJCL's bitArrays is [explicitly subject to change](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/doc/symbols/sjcl.bitArray.html)), but `""` definitely should work.

Answer (score 1):

This is sharing for the rest based on my recent experience.

**My objective:**

To generate PBKDF2 password using Python. The client will be Android (Java), and the back end will be on Flask (Python).

**Issue:**

While testing, I discovered that both versions (Java vs Python) produced different hashing output (all other parameters were equal - SHA256, 1000 iterations, similar SALT)

What I have found out:
Using PBKDF2 generation tools available on the internet, the Android result was an exact match, while the Python was not. So there is a good chance the Python result was somehow skewed .....

**Problem solved:**

While looking for possible explanation in SO, I discovered that the way I converted String to bytes in Python was somehow not entirely correct:

Original code:

```
dk = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', b'base64_message', b'salt', 1000)
```

Working code:

```
dk = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', base64_message.encode(), salt.encode(), 1000)
```

This is probably due to my lack of experience in Python. Hope this note will be of use to others, especially those who are new to Python!